# Styled Components: How to apply styles on hover of parent component (different component files)

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

New to the world of React and Styled Components, so sorry if this is super simple!

I have 2 components, a button and an icon.

Originally these were in the same jsx file and I could achieve what I wanted.  However, since splitting them out, I'm having a hard time getting it back to normal.

Here's my code, I've simplified it and stripped unnecessary code.

*** File 1 - button.jsx ***

```
import Icon from '@sd-component/icon';

class ButtonComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Button>
                <Icon />
            </Button>
        );
    }
}
```

*** File 2 - icon.jsx ***

```
const Icon= styled.i`
    background-color: red

    &:hover,
    ${Button}:hover & { // This line used to work when they were in the same file
        background-color: green;
    }
`


class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Icon />;
    }
}
```

So when I hover on the button, I want the background color of the icon to change.  When they were in the same jsx file, I was able to add this `${Button}:hover &` to my `&:hover` and it would work fine.  Now I'm unsure how to achieve this as the CSS for my icon is in the icon.jsx and the CSS for the button is in it's respective file.

Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: Don't style a parent from a child. It rarely makes sense, a child shouldn't know anything about a parent.

Comment: Maybe it's the missing semicolon after `background-color: red`?